# Eclipse Cannot connect to VM, Socket operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets

Environment:

- win 7 64bit
- Eclipse Mars(64bit)
- MyEclipse2013(64bit)
- installed jdk1.8.0_66(64bit)
- installed jdk1.8.0_121(32bit)

Question:

1. When I run the simple java application project on Eclipse under the
   jdk1.8(64bit) there's no error.But when change jdk1.8 to 32bit the
   project can't run either debug(Cannot connect to VM, Socket
   operation on nonsocket: configureBlocking) why?
2. When the above error happened, go to the task manager -> resource
   monitor -> network.And there check for listening ports two javaw.exe
   occured like the picture below.

   [image]
3. The error didn't happened in MyEclipse under jdk1.8 32bit or 64bit, Why?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you figured out a solution?

Comment: @tnas Sorry,I can't remember how to solve this problem. Maybe u can reinstall ur IDE and jdk and make sure the edition is newest.